# iPhone 5 still has previous owners itunes info

Tags: iphone

I bought an iphone 5 off kijiji and was able to restore it however the previous owner still had it connected to itunes therefore am unable to use it. Hiw do I completely wipe phone clean nd start fresh creating my own itunes account

Comment: Short answer, you can't. You need to contact the previous owner.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

> Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings
>   (c.f. http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT4137#erase your device)

If you cannot erase this way, Apple says (down a bit on that page) that you ought to restore using iTunes, which won't be helpful without the original owner's iTunes backup.

If the device is locked via "Find My iPhone Activation Lock", then you'll need to go through this process:

> http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201441

which requires the previous owner to log into their iCloud account, at http://www.icloud.com/find , then click on the device they sold you, then "Remove From Account".

In general, its a good idea to have the previous owner go through these steps as they're selling the device to you:

> http://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201351

Good luck with this!